# C# ObjectListView BackColor (Windows Forms)

Tags: c#, windows-forms-designer, objectlistview

So I want to set a specific background color of an entire row.

I already achieved this by implementing the following code:

```
foreach(var model in modelList)
            objectListView1.BackColor = model.RowColor;
            objectListView1.AddObject(model);
```

This works as intended. It will iterate through my model list and add the Row Color assigned to it. So my OLV has 2 whole rows highlighted.

The issue lies when I hover my mouse over the row, it will go back to white. It seems like the OLV is refreshing when I preform an action and resetting the BackColor to the default.

How can I prevent this from happening?

Comment: There will be hover function disable it or give the same color. Whenever you hover over a row that CSS will be active and row color changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to permanently set the row color depending on the model.RowColor use the [FormatRow event](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/cs/recipes.html#how-can-i-change-the-colours-of-a-row-or-just-a-cell).

Then you can do something like this:

```
private void olv1_FormatRow(object sender, FormatRowEventArgs e) {
    e.Item.BackColor = model.RowColor;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I will try this out today, thanks!